# How to know drawer state inside react Component onStateChange V5 in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know when the drawer was opened/closed on *onStateChange* (in V4 I could get it from the state, but in V5 I can't find this info). Or any other idea as long as I stay with the component context
 
*App.js*

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function MyDrawer(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer onStateChange={props.onStateChange}>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerType="front" drawerPosition="left">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Properties" component={PropertiesTabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
export default with(MyDrawer)
```

*With.tsx*

```
export function with(Component: any) {
    class PNDContainer extends React.Component {
        child: any;
        componentDidMount() {
            //debugger;
            console.log('PND Mounted - First Time Screen');
        }
        componentWillUnmount() { }
        render() {
            const myHookValue = this.props.myHookValue;
            debugger;
            return (<Component onStateChange={(state) => {
                debugger;
                console.log('Screen Changed');
            }} />)
        }
    }
    return PNDContainer;
}
```

I know that it's possible to implement with functional components (but that's not what I need).
I followed couple of examples with no luck [How to Use React Hooks in Class Components](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-use-react-hooks-in-class-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onStateChange={(state) => {
  const isDrawerOpen = state.history.some((it) => it.type === 'drawer');
}
```

Another option is to use the fiber node tree find the *DraverView* type and check if it's open